# Diagnosing why my MBP keeps crashing and restarting?

Tags: macbook-pro, crash

I am currently getting occasional 'crashes' while running OS X 10.9 on an Early 2011 Macbook Pro. The crashes very much resemble the Blue Screen of Death on Windows (i.e. it happens suddenly, and it triggers an instant restart).

Here is a crash report from the most recent crash. Can anyone see what might be going on?

```
Thu Nov 14 23:01:11 2013
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff80276dc19e): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7fa9c12829, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000000000028, CR3: 0x000000002a290000, CR4: 0x00000000000606e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0xffffff805f77b608, RCX: 0xffffffffffffffff, RDX: 0x000000000000000e
RSP: 0xffffff81fa313c70, RBP: 0xffffff81fa313ca0, RSI: 0x000000000000006a, RDI: 0x000000000000ffff
R8:  0xffffff7fa9c1dd74, R9:  0xffffffffffffff00, R10: 0x00000000000003ff, R11: 0xffffffffffffffff
R12: 0x0000000000000001, R13: 0xffffff804e8a7b48, R14: 0xffffff804f0f6a08, R15: 0x0000000000000020
RFL: 0x0000000000010286, RIP: 0xffffff7fa9c12829, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000028, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x0

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81fa313900 : 0xffffff8027622f69 
0xffffff81fa313980 : 0xffffff80276dc19e 
0xffffff81fa313b50 : 0xffffff80276f3606 
0xffffff81fa313b70 : 0xffffff7fa9c12829 
0xffffff81fa313ca0 : 0xffffff7fa9c12d52 
0xffffff81fa313d00 : 0xffffff7fa8238bf1 
0xffffff81fa313d60 : 0xffffff7fa822d16b 
0xffffff81fa313e30 : 0xffffff8027aae4b3 
0xffffff81fa313e90 : 0xffffff7fa822cc84 
0xffffff81fa313ec0 : 0xffffff8027ab05fb 
0xffffff81fa313f20 : 0xffffff802764a15a 
0xffffff81fa313fb0 : 0xffffff80276d6aa7 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily(2.0)[1185D338-98A5-345E-84F8-E59DF819A61B]@0xffffff7fa820e000->0xffffff7fa827ffff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore(28.30)[558B2575-5197-3C4C-BAD2-8CB465638FA8]@0xffffff7fa8203000
         org.pqrs.driver.KeyRemap4MacBook(9.0)[722DA168-34C5-309C-8DF0-2D51ADCAEC49]@0xffffff7fa9c0a000->0xffffff7fa9c24fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily(2.0.0)[1185D338-98A5-345E-84F8-E59DF819A61B]@0xffffff7fa820e000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
13A603

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 1D9369E3-D0A5-31B6-8D16-BFFBBB390393
Kernel slide:     0x0000000027400000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8027600000
System model name: MacBookPro8,2 (Mac-94245A3940C91C80)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 4118026041294
last loaded kext at 247448385431: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs 1.9 (addr 0xffffff7fa9c25000, size 65536)
last unloaded kext at 307752918395: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.9 (addr 0xffffff7fa9c25000, size 57344)
loaded kexts:
org.pqrs.driver.KeyRemap4MacBook    9.0.0
net.telestream.driver.TelestreamAudio   1.0.5
com.globaldelight.driver.BoomDevice 1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   80.14
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.2.0f6
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.14.11
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   1.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.5.2fc2
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.2.0f6
com.apple.AMDRadeonX3000    1.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.5.2fc2
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.13
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBDisplays   360.8.14
com.apple.kext.AMD6000Controller    1.1.4
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics   8.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB    8.1.8
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.4.12
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.1.12
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 1.0.10
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  325.7
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    650.4.4
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.4.0
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   700.20.22
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.4.0
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.6.9b9
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.9.9
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.9.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   650.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 216.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   153
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   216.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard  170.15
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   170.15
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.2.0f6
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  245.13
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.7
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.5.2fc2
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.2.0f6
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily 98.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio  2.9.3f17
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   1.1.4
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.4.12
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   91
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.2.0f6
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.9.4fc11
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.14
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.4.12
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.11d1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.5.2fc2
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.6
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.5.2fc2
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.6d1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.5.1d27
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIUpAdapter   1.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   2.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    2.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    2.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 1.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 240.6
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  650.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   650.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  650.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    1.9.2
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 2.8.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 650.4.4
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   600.34
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b4
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 650.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  278.10
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 371.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  21
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.8
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
```

Comment: Tips for reading these logs, you want to pay attention to the sections where it says:  "Kernel Extensions in backtrace:", "last loaded kext at", and "loaded kexts:".

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have KeyRemap4MacBook installed which may be causing the problem. If you restart with the [shift] key held down does it make a difference?

Holding the [shift] key down at startup until you get to the login screen and see 'Safe Boot' at the login window prevents 3rd party extensions from loading which will help you determine if it's the KeyRemap4MacBook extension that's causing the problem.

More on Safe Boot here: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1564

<strike>I would hazard a guess that you updated the OS to 10.9 without updating KeyRemap4MacBook to a Mavericks compatible version.</strike>

I looked again, you appear to be running v 9.0 which is the latest version. My guess then would be a messed up preference file or cache.

~W